# Sublime Text 3 + Markdown Preview / Chrome does not render maths equation

Tags: google-chrome, sublimetext3, markdown, mathjax

I'm using having problem rendering maths equations in Chrome with its `Markdown Viewer` plugin.

### System Setup

Sublime Text 3 `v3.2.1 build 3207`
Plugin: Markdown Preview `2.2.4`

Ubuntu 18.06

Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)

### Steps to Preview

My normal setups are:

1. edit in sublime
2. use **Markdown Preivew** to generate **preview in browser**
3. view the generated html in Chrome

This was working fine until maybe a month or so, I can't remember the exact dates..

### Screenshot

Here's is what I see now below. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon this problem as well. [This](https://hang-hu.github.io/sublime/2018/09/10/set-up-math-expression-in-sublime-with-markdown-preview.html) link helped me.
In case it won't be available in the future here are the steps:

1. **Edit MarkdownPreview config**

   Add following config to **user** config of Markdown Preview:
   Preferences -> Package Settings -> Markdown Preview -> Settings

```
    {
    "enable_mathjax": true,
    "js": [
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js",
            "res://MarkdownPreview/js/math_config.js",
    ],
}
```

2. **Install Package​Resource​Viewer**

   Package Contol: Install Package -> Package​Resource​Viewer.
3. **Edit math_config.js**

   Package​Resource​Viewer -> Open Resource -> MarkdownPreview -> js -> math_config.js
   Replace the contents with:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
  jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/NativeMML"],
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
    displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
    processEscapes: true
  },
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js"],
    TagSide: "right",
    TagIndent: ".8em",
    MultLineWidth: "85%",
    equationNumbers: {
      autoNumber: "AMS",
    },
    unicode: {
      fonts: "STIXGeneral,'Arial Unicode MS'"
    }
  },
  displayAlign: "center",
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  messageStyle: 'none'
});
```

Try it. Did the job for me.

Comment: That worked for me! Really appreciate it, this has been bugging me for nearly a year!

Comment: At this time, step #1 was sufficient for me (other steps seem to have been taken care of after a clean install), thanks!